# Access route name in gate

Tags: php, laravel, routes, authorization

Basically, I want to check the route name in my gate definitons.

The routes should be grouped and a single middleware checks a gate to see if access is allowed.
I have looked into the "can" middleware of Laravel 5.4 and I have not found a way to do that, since it does not pass the required information to the gate.

It seems I need to define my own middleware, or am I missing something?

Comment: Put some related code, then point out what exactly you need and trying to fix.

Comment: `$request = resolve(\Illuminate\Http\Request)` and everything you need is in there

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, that's what I was looking for. Although you forgot to add "::class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**apokryfos** Solution was exactly what i needed.

```
$request = resolve(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
```

Now I can access the route name from within the gate.